# Bevel Not Working On Car Seat Model

Tags: modeling

I am having a problem beveling the inner edges on this seat for a car I am making. The design is odd as three different vertices converge to one point so maybe that is giving me a problem. Does anyone know of any way to achieve the same effect on these edges. Thanks for any help you may provide.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be an issue due to clamping, which prevents the bevel from generating non-manifold (i.e. self-intersecting) geometry. Try turning this off in the modifier settings and you should see what's happening. It'll probably be due to some of the very short edges meaning the clamping causes the bevel width to be clamped very small (small enough to make the bevel virtually invisible).

Comment: Thank you for the message. I checked and I have clamping turned off. I am back to square one.

Comment: Are you using vertex/edge bevel weights? If so, check that the edges you want have a weighting more than zero (ideally 1).